# PHP can if statement have two values?

Tags: php, if-statement

I was trying out a PHP "if" statement in which I want two things to be true: that $myvar is equal to 1 and that $myvar2 is equal to 2. However when I tried this:

```
if($myvar=='1', $myvar2=='2') {
header("location:index.php");
}
```

It failed to work. **Is there a way to set up one if statement to contain these two variables like I have presented?**
Thank you

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: Yes, connect them with a [logical and operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

Comment: Have you considered a PHP book or tutorial? This is an *extremely* basic question. Use `and` instead of a comma.

Comment: @Francis Avila, I have, certainly, but I have only been using PHP for just about... three days now so I will probably read and learn more about it later on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the boolean AND operator (&&)

```
if($myvar=='1' && $myvar2=='2') {
    header("location:index.php");
}
```

Here's a full list of operators: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: Oh okay! Thanks sorry I'm kind of new so I didn't know about that

Answer (score 1):

This will do. It is essential that you learn more about operators and flow control.

```
if($myvar=='1' && $myvar2=='2') {
header("location:index.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "and" operator `&&`

Answer (score 0):

The && operator is the same as writing x='1' AND y='2',
So in ur case
    `if($myvar=='1' && $myvar2=='2') {`

You can read more about PHP's operators at http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php